# Looking to get into Ancient Greek poetry in the original

Tags: resource-request, greek, poetry

I'm am currently an undergraduate in college studying Classical Languages. I know Koine Greek, and read through Geoffrey Steadman's edition of Plato's Apology, which I found a helpful introduction to Attic.

If I'm looking for an introduction to Greek poetry in the original language, where should I go? Are there helpful introductory textbooks to this sort of thing?